# How can I fix my CSS so it looks right?

Tags: html, css

I have customised the CSS of the view button and add to cart button

```
  .sj_vm_deals_wrap .item:hover .sj_vm_deals_popup{

display:block;
 filter: alpha(opacity=10000);
-webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
-moz-transform: translate(0,0);
-ms-transform: translate(0,0);
-o-transform: translate(0,0);
transform: translate(0,0);
transition: all 0.666666666666667s ease 0s;
}
```

And

```
  .sj_vm_deals_wrap .item .sj_vm_deals_popup{

display:block;
 filter: alpha(opacity=10000);
-webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
-moz-transform: translate(0,0);
-ms-transform: translate(0,0);
-o-transform: translate(0,0);
transform: translate(170px,0);
transition: all 0.666666666666667s ease 0s;
 }
```

before it was only :

```
.sj_vm_deals_wrap .item:hover .sj_vm_deals_popup{

display:block;

}
```

But now when you hover on products you will see that the slide-in-from-outside effect looks not correct. How can I fix this?

you can see it here : ibn.reviewcost.com

Comment: What do you mean not looks correct?

Comment: tell us what you are expecting and what you have got? then we all can suggest whats wrong.

Comment: also i mean when you hover on the product the buttons must be hided  at the end of the product as you look in this screen https://www.screencast.com/t/O3zHl0jxPd  and those buttons must be hided under the Product too https://www.screencast.com/t/JmVZfK477 you can look here that you look what i mean in this template it works correctly when whe  you hover on the Featured  products http://joomla.vinagecko.net/t/vina_ifoody/

Comment: In order for a question to be on-topic here, we need (a) a good description that is more than "it does not look correct", and (b) a demonstration of the problem that is not the actual web site in question. External links to your work will naturally expire when you delete a demo site or fix the problem, and when that happens, the question will make even less sense. Can you add a JS Fiddle or Stack Snippet to illustrate the issue? A screenshot might help as well, and perhaps also a detailed description of the problem.

Comment: Please read: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/472495)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are (probably) looking for:

```
.owl-carousel .item {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Which removes the 'not correct' slide-in-from-outside effect.

Comment: If I visit that URL, open the console (I'm on Chrome) and add `overflow: hidden` to `.owl-carousel .item`, the buttons are perfectly visible on hover. Which browser are you using?

Comment: sorry i have copy past you css cod and it was not complete because you vorget the "{" so when i added it it was fixed

Comment: thanks for you help , i have updated the question too , , i have an other small question : how can i change the transition: all 0.666666666666667s ease 0s; only for the "item-view button" so that slid in after the "add to cart button "  this an exapmle of how it must look http://joomla.vinagecko.net/t/vina_ifoody/index.php/virtuemart/shop-layout/grid-products  the buttons here slid in one after the other ..  , can i do the same ?